# Paginar objetos de un mismo loop en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un ligero problema,

He logrado iterar 2 objetos en un mismo each, mi problema es que este no funciona con `will_paginate`, y para poder hacer esa iteración me apoyo del método de Ruby: `sort_by` pero aparentemente este no funciona con ninguna gema de paginación, que sugerencia me dan, espero puedan echarme una mano, aquí les comparto mi código:

enterprises_controller.rb

```
def show
  @items = @enterprise.jobs + @enterprise.products
  @items = @items.sort_by do |item| item.created_at end
  @items = @items.reverse
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @items = @items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.name %> <br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: La estructura de jobs y products es similar ?

Comment: Que tal Joel, no capto tu idea?

Comment: Es bastante similar, pero tienen varios campos de diferencia, no mucho talvez unos 2 o 3

Comment: Si vas a usar un bloque en una sola linea es mejor usar `{}` que `do end`
`@items = @items.sort_by { |item| item.created_at }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso, deberías usar el método `sort` para un arreglo el cual tiene la siguiente estructura y te permite ordenar un arreglo cualquiera por alguno de los atributos de sus objetos.

```
my_array.sort! { |a, b|  a.attribute <=> b.attribute }
```

En este caso, el resultado seria muy similar a:

```
my_array = @items.sort! { |a, b|  a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
```

Para la paginación necesitas usar ademas de `will_paginate` su modulo para arreglos, con `require 'will_paginate/array'`

El cual se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
my_array.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

Comment: ¿En donde agrego el requiere Joel?

Comment: Va genial lo logre Joel! Muchas gracias!

Comment: `sort!` modifica el array. Es mejor hacer `my_array = @items.sort { |a, b|  a.created_at <=> b.created_at }`. De este modo @items queda sin modificar. Si quieres modificar @items, entonces no es necesario asignarlo a my_array

Comment: Ten en cuenta también que ordenarlo de esta manera es mucho menos eficiente que ordenarlo con una query a la base de datos.

Comment: @hcarreras tienes razón, es mejor usar el sort, sobre lo de ordenar fuera del query también es relativo según el caso, a veces se prefiere evitar las conexiones a datos, cuando el tratamiento de datos es únicamente un esfuerzo de presentación.

Comment: @JoelIbaceta hay que tener en cuenta que rails junta todas las queries que hagas sobre una relación (siempre que sigas manipulando la misma relación) en una sola. Por lo que si ordenas los datos cuando los piden a la bd será más eficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui el proceso:

Dentro de un archivo en **config/initializers**, puede ser "**will_paginate.rb**", se agrega: `require 'will_paginate/array'`

Y el controller me quedo asi:

```
def show
    @items = @enterprise.jobs + @enterprise.products
    @items = @items.sort! { |a, b|  a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
    @items = @items.reverse.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
end
```

y la vista de show:

```
<%= will_paginate @items, :container => false %>
```